# Conda virtual environment / Plotly issue

Tags: python, anaconda, yaml, conda

I've tried to create the following environment with Anaconda Spyder:

```yaml
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
name:env_dash 
dependencies:
    - python=3.8.3
    - pip
    - pip:
        - numpy==1.18.5
        - pandas==1.0.5
        - plotly==5.4.0
        - dash==2.0.0
        - gunicorn==20.1.0
```

But when I try to create it I get an error:

```bash
(base) PS D:\environments> conda env create -f Env_dash.yml

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_env\cli\main.py", line 80, in do_call
        exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_env\cli\main_create.py", line 79, in execute
        spec = specs.detect(name=name, filename=expand(args.file),
      File "C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_env\specs\__init__.py", line 40, in detect
        if spec.can_handle():
      File "C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_env\specs\yaml_file.py", line 18, in can_handle
        self._environment = env.from_file(self.filename)
      File "C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_env\env.py", line 151, in from_file
        return from_yaml(yamlstr, filename=filename)
      File "C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_env\env.py", line 136, in from_yaml
        data = yaml_load_standard(yamlstr)
      File "C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\serialize.py", line 76, in yaml_load_standard
        return yaml.load(string, Loader=yaml.Loader, version="1.2")
      File "C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel_yaml\main.py", line 935, in load
        return loader._constructor.get_single_data()
      File "C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel_yaml\constructor.py", line 109, in get_single_data
        node = self.composer.get_single_node()
      File "C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel_yaml\composer.py", line 78, in get_single_node
        document = self.compose_document()
      File "C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel_yaml\composer.py", line 104, in compose_document
        self.parser.get_event()
      File "C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel_yaml\parser.py", line 163, in get_event
        self.current_event = self.state()
      File "C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel_yaml\parser.py", line 239, in parse_document_end
        token = self.scanner.peek_token()
      File "C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel_yaml\scanner.py", line 182, in peek_token
        self.fetch_more_tokens()
      File "C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel_yaml\scanner.py", line 282, in fetch_more_tokens
        return self.fetch_value()
      File "C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel_yaml\scanner.py", line 651, in fetch_value
        raise ScannerError(
    ruamel_yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
      in "<unicode string>", line 3, column 13:
        dependencies:
                    ^ (line: 3)

$ C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-env-script.py create -f Env_dash.yml`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>   CONDA_AUTO_UPDATE_CONDA=false
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
                CONDA_EXE=C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
             CONDA_PREFIX=C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\python.exe
               CONDA_ROOT=C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
                 HOMEPATH=\Users\hugoa
                     PATH=C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3;C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bi
                          n;C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\Li
                          brary\bin;C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\bi
                          n;C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3;C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\
                          bin;C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\
                          Library\bin;C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\
                          bin;C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\condabin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
                          Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS
                          Client;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDO
                          WS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
                          ;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
                          Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
                          Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
                          Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
                          Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common F
                          iles\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Users\hugoa\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windo
                          wsApps;D:\Software-Hugo\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\src\flutter\bin;.
             PSMODULEPATH=C:\Users\hugoa\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\Wi
                          ndowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Mod
                          ules
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>
    VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH=D:\Virtual box\

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\hugoa\.condarc  populated config files : C:\Users\hugoa\.condarc
          conda version : 4.8.3
    conda-build version : 3.18.11
         python version : 3.8.3.final.0
       virtual packages :
       base environment : C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\hugoa\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\hugoa\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\hugoa\anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\hugoa\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\hugoa\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.3 requests/2.18.1 CPython/3.8.3 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19041
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve future releases of conda.
```

Has anyone solved this before?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a YAML formatting issue. Note that YAML is whitespace-sensitive. The following works fine for me:

**Env_dash.yaml**

```yaml
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
name: env_dash 
dependencies:
  - python=3.8.3
  - pip
  - pip:
    - numpy==1.18.5
    - pandas==1.0.5
    - plotly==5.4.0
    - dash==2.0.0
    - gunicorn==20.1.0
```

Please consult [the YAML specification](https://yaml.org). There are also online validators available.